# Trying to share Metal texture with Opengl texture

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, metal

I looked in the documentation, but I don't know how to get the texture ID.
I'm actually getting a metal texture from an SDK and I would like to share it with Ogre Texture. My issue That code compiles but I don't know how to get the texture ID so that I can use it for Ogre to render it. The code crashes, and it doesn't work at all. I spent a lot of time to struct it. Hope that someone saves my time.

For example it crashes now at this line, however ioSurface is initialized

```
        id<MTLTexture> metalTexture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDescriptor
                                                                  ioSurface:surface
                                                                      plane:0];
```

unrecognized selector sent to instance

--

```
void* texPtr = SixDegreesSDK_GetBackgroundTexture();
            if (texPtr != nil) {
                id<MTLTexture> mtlTexture = (__bridge id<MTLTexture>)texPtr;

                id<MTLDevice> device = [mtlTexture device];
                // !!! Not fond of creating a new command queue for every texture
                id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];
                id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
                id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];

                NSUInteger textureWidth = mtlTexture.width;
                NSUInteger textureHeight = mtlTexture.height;
                NSUInteger rowbytes = mtlTexture.bufferBytesPerRow;
                MTLPixelFormat  pixFormat = mtlTexture.pixelFormat;
                CVPixelBufferRef _CVPixelBuffer = NULL;
                NSDictionary* cvBufferProperties = @{
                                                     (__bridge NSString*)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLCompatibilityKey : @YES,
                                                     (__bridge NSString*)kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey : @YES,
                                                     };
                CVReturn cvret = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                     textureWidth, textureHeight,
                                                     kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA,
                                                     (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)cvBufferProperties,
                                                     &_CVPixelBuffer);
                const IOSurfaceRef surface  = CVPixelBufferGetIOSurface(_CVPixelBuffer);             // available in ios11 sdk, ios4 runtime

                MTLTextureDescriptor* textureDescriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:pixFormat
                                                                                                             width:textureWidth
                                                                                                            height:textureHeight
                                                                                                         mipmapped:NO];
                id<MTLTexture> metalTexture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDescriptor
                                                                          ioSurface:surface
                                                                              plane:0];

                MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight);

                [blitEncoder copyFromTexture:mtlTexture
                                 sourceSlice:0
                                 sourceLevel:0
                                sourceOrigin:region.origin
                                  sourceSize:region.size
                                   toTexture:metalTexture
                            destinationSlice:0
                            destinationLevel:0
                           destinationOrigin:region.origin];

                [blitEncoder endEncoding];
                [commandBuffer commit];
                [self.mEAGLContext texImageIOSurface:surface target:GL_TEXTURE_2D internalFormat:GL_RGBA width:textureWidth height:textureHeight format:GL_RGBA type:GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE plane:0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* what you want would be `CVOpenGLTextureGetName`. I believe this returns the texture ID of the texture you pass into it.